# AWS EC2 Instance Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have a new account on AWS and by default i can create only 1 VM on demand on US EAST N. VIRGINA us-east-1. This appear to me very strange, i have sent an email to tyhe support to allow me to create more instance but i bet taht i have to configure something. Can someone help me to understand if this is normal?

following a screenshot of the error that i see when i launch a new instance on-demand

[image: Instance Limits error]

Comment: That's nuttier'n a shit-house rat. I've never seen that before and I've been through the process of upping the limit many times.  My guess is that they don't have any resources available in that region/zone for that instance type currently. Curious to know what their support team has to say.

Comment: So currently you have 0 running EC2 instances? If you look in your EC2 instance list, it's empty or all existing EC2 instances are stopped?

Comment: Which instance type are you trying to launch? You have different limits for each instance type.

Comment: I have 1 instance t2.medium and want create another instance c4.2xlarge. This thing really sucks. With Azure i can create whatever i want. I this case i need to use aws but i'm aghast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the link and ask that the limit be increased.  Once that is done, you won't have to ask again unless you need even more resources than the new limit.

> You are limited to running up to a total of 20 On-Demand instances across the instance family, purchasing 20 Reserved Instances, and requesting Spot Instances per your dynamic Spot limit per region. **New AWS accounts may start with limits that are lower than the limits described here.** *(emphasis added)*.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2

It stands to reason that new accounts are a significant source of fraudulent activity, so new accounts may have lower limits than "normal."

Comment: I'm following up to notify you that we've received your EC2  limit increase request for 2 for c4.2xlarge in the US East (Northern Virginia), and I’m happy to submit the request for you.

For a limit increase of this type, I will need to collaborate with our Service Team to get approval. Please note that it can take some time for the Service Team to review your request. This is to ensure that we can meet your needs while keeping existing infrastructure safe.

You are our valuable customer and I really appreciate your patience while we evaluate the limit increase request for you.

Comment: This is the response by the support. AWS rly sucks indeed now the resource they waste my time. With azure never had this problems

Comment: How do I view status of current limits?