# How to view the ec2 instance limits on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am unable to launch requested AWS instance due to limits on my account. Where is the page showing what the limits actually *are*?

Note this question is different than the one here [AWS EC2 Instance Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572766/aws-ec2-instance-limits) - which just asks how to request an increase. I already have done so and can not get *more* : but would like to see what I *can* use.

[image]

Comment: *"already have done so and can not get more"* ...that doesn't sound right.  What did you ask for, in which region, and what did they say when your request was declined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Its right here.

Also these non coding question do not gather much interest here on SoF